# Magento - send copy of message from contact form to sender

Tags: forms, email, magento, magento-1.9

I have got simple contact form with custom fields which is used for contact purpose. How can i set up this form to send **copy of the message** to sender ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such configuration option in magento.

You may create custom module in local namespace, where you override controller class Mage_Contacts_IndexController and change the code of postAction() method to add addBcc() method inside. Like this:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
    ->addBcc($post['email'])
    ->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
        null,
        array('data' => $postObject)
    );
```